# What frameworks to analyze a reponse of a REST service?

Tags: java, xml, json, frameworks

I'm using a REST webservice to retrieve some data. As a response I get some long xml or other files. Part of it could look for example like this:

```
<jfs:jauthRevokeTokenUrl
      rdf:resource="https://localhost:9443/jts/jauth-revoke-token" />

  <jfs:jauthCheckAuthUrl
      rdf:resource="https://localhost:9443/jts/jauth-check-auth" />

  <jfs:jauthProxyUrl
      rdf:resource="https://localhost:9443/jts/jauth-proxy" />

  <jfs:jauthSigninUrl
      rdf:resource="https://localhost:9443/jts/jauth-signin" />
```

If I now want to retrieve the value of `rdf:resource` of for example the node `jfs:jautSigningURL`, what Java framework can I use for this? And what if the response is not xml but json? What frameworks can I use then? Or do I have to code this by myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to avoid any big framework, you could look at the build in tools of java for parsing XML

Here an example, assuming you have an `XML` string variable

```
 DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

 DocumentBuilder db = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
 InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(XML.getBytes());
 Document parsed = db.parse(inputStream);

 parsed.getDocumentElement().normalize();
 Node tag = parsed.getElementsByTagName("jfs:jauthSigninUrl").item(0);
 String value = tag.getAttributes().getNamedItem("rdf:resource").getNodeValue();
```

You could further refine that by including namespace definitions, null checks and maybe simplifying it with an XPath expression, like so

```
 XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
 String value = xpath.evaluate("//jauthSigninUrl/@resource", parsed);
```

See here [Java XML XPATH](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/xml/validationxpath/)

Answer (score 1):

you might want to consider [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/), it can help you read and parse many formats (including but not limited to XML, json)..

here json can be treated as plain text file and parsed properly using [Json](http://json.org/)